# How do I compute an average when one of the measurements couldn't be measured?

Tags: mean, censoring

In my biology class we were doing a lab on respiration rates of peas. We used a respirometer with a small pipet tube (markings up to 1 mL) to measure the volume of gas; by immersing in water, the gas and water would remain separate and the level of water could be measured on the pipet, giving the amount of gas inside and therefore the respiration rates. However, at one point, the water level went beyond the highest mark on the pipet; the peas had used more than 1 mL of air for respiration. Now I'm supposed to find the average gas usage (other class groups did the same thing but none had peas use more than 1 mL of gas). How do I compute the class average? Do I exclude my data point for those trials?

In short, I couldn't measure the amount of gas used by peas because they used more than the pipet could measure. Other groups doing the same experiment didn't have this problem, so how do I find the average gas usage?

Comment: How many measurements / peas were there? Is it reasonable to assume that the measurements followed a normal distribution, or a symmetrical distribution?

Comment: There were 4 other class groups who made the measurements. This makes it really difficult to decide.

Comment: Each respirometer had 25 peas in it but the respiration rate was taken as the sum of all of the 25 peas. We didn't measure the rates of each individual peas, just all 25 as a whole.

Comment: So you have 1 measurement per 25 peas, & there were 5 measurements (of which 1 was above the scale), is that right? Is there any good / theoretical reason to assume the data follow a symmetrical distribution?

Comment: @gung yeah that's correct. And I have no idea how to think  of an answer to that question. I've never studied normal distributions or anything like that in an intro stats course. All I know I standard deviation and averages and medians...

Comment: To give some idea of where @gung is going: you can't take an *average* of anything but the data you have, but you can still be interested in the (true) *mean* - something the average gives you information about. Usually the average is itself an estimate of the true mean and things are easy. Here the average you can take is *not* a very good estimate because it will be too small due to the censoring at 0.1. Consequently he is thinking of how to build a statistical model of the measurement process so that he can take into account the censoring and estimate the mean better. (1/2)

Comment: To build that model he wonders if the measurements would have noise that is symmetrical around the true mean if there were no censoring at 0.1.  If it did then it might be reasonable to think of the measurement noise having a Normal distribution. Knowing the distribution makes things easier because we can compute what the chances are of those >0.1 measurements for different true means. It also makes it possible to choose an estimated value for the true mean that makes the data most probable, taking into account the censoring. That value - not the average - will be a better estimate (2/2)

Comment: @conjugateprior thanks for your insight. From a scientific ethics/scientific procedure, what is the proper way of handling it? Basically if we are more worried about following standard scientific procedure and transparency over necessary accuracy

Comment: From the scientific procedure perspective, you report an estimated mean and confidence interval using an analysis that takes into account the censoring. Certainly, silently throwing away a high value and reporting an estimate that will be too small seems a bit questionable, but your discipline probably has rather definite procedures for dealing with censored measurements that we probably don't know about.

Comment: ...but from the perspective of taking a biology class I wouldn't know how serious you're expected to be. If you haven't met very much statistics I'd guess nobody is expecting you to do a full-on censored data analysis.

Comment: @conjugateprior this is AP biology in high school. This is our introduction to statistics in this class so nothing high tech beyond error bar type things I imagine.

Comment: This isn't the final step in our data analysis, the teacher is going to talk a bit more about the next steps in our analysis tomorrow in class I think.

Comment: Then I'd recommend first reporting the average as if there was no censoring. Then note directly afterwards that using that average as an estimate of the true mean will be downward biased, but that its not possible for you to say how far down without doing more statistics than you currently know how to do. You now have the preview for what those statistics would be, so you're a little bit ahead of the game. And if you ever eventually need to do a censored analysis - well - you know where to find us... :-)

Comment: @conjugateprior thanks so much for all of your help.

Comment: @conjugateprior, why not write that up as the official answer? For the sake of clarity, Faraz, "reporting the average as if there was no censoring" means use the .1 max reading as the value to be included in the average, not ignore it & just take the average of the other 4 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's for a class I'd recommend the following:

- Report the average as if there was no censoring, treating the censored value as 0.1.
- Note that this average is, as an estimator of the true mean, *downward-biased*, so you'd expect the true mean to be a bit higher.
- Also note that it's not possible to say *how far* the average will be biased without doing a more sophisticated statistical analysis that takes into account the censoring.